# Using SQLCMD on Ubuntu not updating Azure SQL database

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure-sql-database, sqlcmd

I have SQLCMD on a Ubuntu machine. I parse many XML files and generate Insert/Update/Delete statements and save them in an .sql file. So a single .sql file contains many sql statements. They all are enclosed in transaction. 
I run the SQLCMD utility passing the file as an argument. My database is an Azure SQL.
I never get an error result, but a lot of time, my database is not being updated. I do not get any clue that why that is happening, because there is no error. If I run those .sql file directly on the server, it updates the database.

Is there a way I can trace out/debug on what is happening?

Here is my SQLCMD command

```
$sqlcmd -i mysqlFile.sql -m-1 -p
```

The Database configuration is set in the environment variables.

**EDIT**

Adding more detail, I am running a shell script which generates many sql files and then executes those on Azure SQL. Each sql file has a transaction and many DML statements inside the transaction. It also has proper try/catch enclosing.
DUring the process, some of the SQL files are properly executed and update the database, but for some, nothing gets changed. I do not see any error on executing of SQLCMD, it just says "0 rows affected". Once a sql file fails, all the subsequent sql fails too.
Can this be an issue whith network/firewall?

Comment: Try to specify the Azure SQL server name. sqlcmd –S yourServerName.database.windows.net – U yourUsername – P yourPassword

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
echo :setvar param1 DUMMYVALUE > param_input.sql
cat input.sql >> param_input.sql
sqlcmd –S yourServerName.database.windows.net -d database -U user -P pass -i param_input.sql
```

Comment: This didn't help. The error is random. I added some more detail to the question